# Unexpected characters in console output

Tags: c++, string, c++03, crysis

I am programming a new server-client network for the game Crysis Wars.
I have a function that centers a string to the amount of characters supported per-line in the console window.
The window fits 113 characters, but I have set the maximum character width in my function to `111` as to fit text nicely.

This is my function:

```
string Main::CenterText(string s)
{
    return string((111 - s.length()) / 2, ' ') + s; 
}
```

This function is from a [question I asked last year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17512825/align-text-to-center-in-string-c), but I however am not sure whether I ended up using it or not *in past projects*.

I am attempting to use this function in this context (the `CryLogAlways` function simply logs the string to the game/server logfile and prints it):

```
CryLogAlways(CenterText("   ____     ____      _ __      _  _  __").c_str());
CryLogAlways(CenterText("  /  _/__  / _(_)__  (_) /___ _( )| |/_/").c_str());
CryLogAlways(CenterText(" _/ // _ \\/ _/ / _ \\/ / __/ // //_>  <  ").c_str());
CryLogAlways(CenterText("/___/_//_/_//_/_//_/_/\\__/\\_, / /_/|_|  ").c_str());
CryLogAlways(CenterText("                         /___/          ").c_str());
```

However the output is:

[image]

Likewise as @deW1 requested, I have a similar output with `CryLogAlways(CenterText("X").c_str());`:

[image]

Why am I getting this output, and how can I fix this?

Comment: What is the output if you do `CryLogAlways(CenterText("X").c_str());` ?

Comment: @deW1 http://puu.sh/cZEG8/7921d3bc39.png. It's a strange issue, I'll put that into the question.

Comment: what do you mean by "I however am not sure whether I ended up using it or not" ? Are you sure that the `Main::CenterText` function that you showed is the actual one that you're using ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I updated the sentence for clarity. I was referring to past projects, and not my current one.

Comment: If that's a `CryString`, they've inverted the order of parameters for construction of a `string`: First the value, then the amount (as opposed to `std::string`). The character `' '` is 32 decimal, which corresponds to the amount of `'#'`characters in your output.

Comment: @dyp The `CryLogAlways` here takes a `const char *`, but it could very well be converted to `CryString` within its function. I'll check.

Comment: @cybermonkey Well your function uses a type named `string` as both its parameter and return type, and within this function, you're constructing a `string` - here, the order of parameters matters.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly `string` is?

Comment: @Angew It's a standard C++ `string` type. The `CryString` type that @dyp refers to can be used as` `CryString` in place of `string`, but I've never actually used `CryString`.

Comment: @cybermonkey: Apparently it's _not_ `std::string`...

Comment: @cybermonkey Does anything change if you explicitly qualify it as `std::string` in all occurences in the function? It's obviously interpreting `' '` (ASCII 32) as the number of characters, which `std::string` should most definitely not do.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It certainly *is* `std::string`, and it's definitely ***not*** `CryString`.

Comment: @cybermonkey: Then what's all this about the arguments being switched?

Comment: @Angew Just tested that, and it's now outputting the desired text correctly. If you (or someone else) write out an answer detailing *why* simply using a normal `string` type won't work (and perhaps a revised function), I'll accept the answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I have no idea. I've done a few C++ Crysis DLL projects with the supplied SDK, and this is the first time I've heard anyone say that the arguments are switched.

Comment: @cybermonkey: No one needs to "say" it; it's clear from both the documentation and [the source](http://www.gamedev.stjepan.net/ce3sdk/docs/CryEngine/html/_cry_string_8h_source.html).

Comment: @cybermonkey: The normal `[std::]string` type will work just fine; but currently you're _not_ using it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Surely to use that type I would have to use `CryString` (and `#include` its header), or am I missing something here?

Comment: @cybermonkey: Sorry but I have no idea what you're talking about. No to use `std::string` you do not have to use `CryString`; that makes no sense! Write `std::string` in full to stop the compiler thinking that by `string` you instead mean `CryString`. Or simply reverse your arguments.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I apologise; I looked into it further and it *is* using `CryString`.

Comment: @cybermonkey Yes as we've all been saying all along :P

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Strange, I've worked on C++ projects for this game for a couple of years now, and never noticed that. I guess we all learn something new every day :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using the type `string` unqualified. I was assuming you have `using namespace std` somewhere ([against best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1782465)), which would make `string` refer to `std::string`. But apparently that is not the case, and you have the non-qualified name `string` defined to *something* (the question doesn't show what), which behaves similarly to a `std::string` (i.e. it has `.length()` and `.c_str()`). However, the constructor arguments of this *something* seem to be in reversed order to those of `std::string`.

If you want your function to work with standard library strings, say so eplicitly:

```
std::string Main::CenterText(std::string s)
{
    return std::string((111 - s.length()) / 2, ' ') + s; 
}
```

This is a prime example of why it's an extremely good idea to use explicit qualification for `std` types.

Comment: *"This is a prime example of why it's an extremely good idea to use explicit qualification for std types."* I would rather assume CryTek used the `typedef CryString string` on purpose to exploit that bad practice: the interface of `CryString` looks very similar to `std::string`, I bet they tried to make it compatible.

Comment: I keep referring back to this, excellent answer so I'm awarding a bounty. Will award in 23 hours.

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ Thanks; I'm happy it's been helpful.

Answer (score 2):

According to [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/), you are right.

As pointed out in the comments, for the string implementation you use, the arguments are switched.

For the second example, you print the sign (111-1)/2 = 55 = '7' for ' ' = 32 times. 
Swap the arguments to

```
string(' ',(111 - s.length()) / 2)
```

and it should work better.

Comment: This is on the right track, though. The compiler is clearly not matching this code to the std::string constructor for 'string (size_t n, char c);'  But the OP tested using a string constant "X" and got the same result, so how can it not be std::string?

Comment: @RichardSchwartz [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) has a constructor that takes the amount of repetition first, then the character to repeat. [CryString](https://github.com/adithedude007/alecmercer-origins/blob/master/Code/CryEngine/CryCommon/CryString.h) on the other hand first takes the character to repeat, then the amount of repetition. So Martze has it backwards.

Comment: So i made the same error as in the question but with the reference version. Wow. Fixed it though.